# Not able to access Fuse Admin console

Tags: jbossfuse

I have started server using fuse_home/bin/start. Server is appearing as started but not able to access Admin console.

It is showing hawtio screen instead.

Appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a fabric first, by using the `fabric:create` command.

Answer (score 0):

- Fuse can be started in two ways one is using **./fuse** script from bin dir
  Another starting in background  **./start** and connect using **./client**
- **./client** connect to running fuse karaf console

  [kkakarla@kkakarla bin]$ ./start
  [kkakarla@kkakarla bin]$ ./status

Running ...
[kkakarla@kkakarla bin]$ ./client
Logging in as admin

Open a browser to http://localhost:8181 to access the management console

Create a new Fabric via 'fabric:create'
or join an existing Fabric via 'fabric:join [someUrls]'

Hit '' or 'osgi:shutdown' to shutdown JBoss Fuse.
JBossFuse:admin@root>

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you uncommented last line user.properties file before starting the fuse server. Fuse provides access to fuse management console using HOWTIO. Since you are starting fuse by using /.start you may not be able to create fabric directly until you connect to client, in that case you can connect to fuse server using SSH @localhost -p8101, then you can run fabric: create. Otherwise you can /.stop the server and start using ./fuse or ./karaf then you can run fabric commands directly. If still issue not resolved we have to check logs.